# How to customize a form/POST in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, forms, post

Hey guys, this has been plaguing me all week long. I am new to Rails, so please be gentle :)

My root problem is I'm trying to write a form_for Post that will use autocompletion on an input to tie the post to a Client. The database is looking for a client_id, not a text name. 
So I have tried a custom validation that will lookup the text value and replace it with an id.
My Post.rb file has this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    attr_accessor :client_name
    attr_accessible :client_name
    before_validation_on_create :validate_client

    def validate_client
        self.client_id = 1 # just a test
    end

    def client_exists(passed_name)
      return Client.where(:full_name => passed_name).first.blank?
    end
end
```

**But when I do this, none of the form variables get passed. The database gets all blank entries except for the client_id.** How can I accomplish this? Why aren't my form variables being passed in? Many thanks in advance.

Edit 1: added create definition from posts_controller.rb

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { 
            redirect_to(posts_url) # redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.')        
        }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Edit 2: Thanks to @apneadiving, I changed the attr_accesible to include the other attributes, and that passes the POST entries into the db.

```
attr_accessible :client_id, :time, :content, :client_name
```

But when I change the validate_client function to search for the client_id,

```
def validate_client
    passed_name = self.client_name

    if client_exists(passed_name)
        c = Client.where(:full_name => passed_name).first
        self.client_id = c.id
    else
        errors.add_to_base "Error"
    end
end
```

It always gives me this error:

> Called id for nil, which would
>   mistakenly be 4 -- if you really
>   wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Edit 3: Here's my post form. I can't get the value of :client_name properly.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'common/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :content %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :content, :size => "50x6" %>
    </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="sub-field">
      <%= f.label :client_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :client_name, :size => "26" %>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-field">
      <%= f.label :date %><br />
      <%= f.text_field(:time, :class => 'date', :size => "10", :value => Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')) %>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-field">
      <%= f.label :time %><br />
      <%= f.time_select :time %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions clear">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Edit 4: The solution.** I was struggling to get the :client_name due to my text being too far tabbed in (I was originally privatizing the function and then took the word "private" out). A modified version of @apneadiving's answer solved it for me!

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    attr_accessor :client_name
    validate :validate_client

    def validate_client
        passed_name = self.client_name

        unless client = Client.find_by_full_name(passed_name).blank?
          self.client_id = Client.find_by_full_name(passed_name).id
        else
          errors.add(:client_name, "'#{passed_name}' cannot be found.")
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Hi painteddigital, when a web request is made (e.g. a POST), the code that handles it is in a controller (usually defined by the routes). It may be helpful to list the code you're using in the controller as well in getting an answer to this particular question.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I added it, though it's pretty generic. Created via scaffolding.

Comment: beware of your attr_acessible, if you set one, you have to set all the variables that can be set through params. Otherwise they are protected against mass assignment

Comment: @apneadiving Awesome tip! I did not know that. So, I added the other variables to the file, but for some odd reason there is an error looking up the client_id. I commented above.

Comment: seems c.id is nil which means your `client_exists` function doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of your `attr_acessible`:

if you set one, you have to set all the variables that can be set through params. Otherwise they are protected against `mass assignment`

EDIT 1:

seems `c.id` is nil which means your `client_exists` function doesn't work as expected. Try the following (not tested):

```
def validate_client
  unless client = Client.find_by_full_name(client_name).nil?
    client_id = client.id
  else
    errors.add_to_base "Error"
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code looks fantastic, but when I try it, I am met with a "406 Not Acceptable" error. So I kept trying to figure out what the problem was and I learned by storing the client_name into the content field that it is coming over as blank. 

This comes back to my original issue of not understanding how to manipulate POST data. :client_name is just a text_field that I created for later looking up the :client_id. Is there an easy way to do that or a resource I should read? I've added my _post.html.erb above.

Comment: Hi again, I don't really understand the pb. For curiosity's sake, could I see the part of your `schema.rb` describing the models?

Comment: Got it sorted! Thanks for your help. I thought the 406 was because of the info submitted, but it was actually due to processing the error with JS and not having a JS responder. The blank data was because I had accidentally tabbed in too far I think. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your `client_exists` code is wrong, it returns true if it doesn't exist.
Also, since your `client_exists` and the `validation` reuse the same query i would rewrite that a bit.

```
def validate_client
  passed_name = self.client_name

  existing_client = Client.where(:full_name => passed_name).first
  if existing_client
    self.client_id = existing_client.id
  else
    errors.add_to_base "Error"
  end
end
```